# ggfortify autoplot timeseries x-axis is not as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, ggfortify

I'm trying to create a facet plot from timeseries data ...

```
if(!require('fma')){
    install.packages("fma")
    library(fma)
}
if(!require('ggfortify')){
    install.packages("ggfortify")
    library(ggfortify)
}
ec <- ts(econsumption, frequency = 12)
ec
```

Which results in ...

```
       Mwh temp
Jan 1 16.3 29.3
Feb 1 16.8 21.7
Mar 1 15.5 23.7
Apr 1 18.2 10.4
May 1 15.2 29.7
Jun 1 17.5 11.9
Jul 1 19.8  9.0
Aug 1 19.0 23.4
Sep 1 17.5 17.8
Oct 1 16.0 30.0
Nov 1 19.6  8.6
Dec 1 18.0 11.8
```

However, when I try to plot, the x-axis isn't as expected ...

```
autoplot(ec, facet=T)
```

The output ...

[image]

I was expecting autoplot to automatically set 12 months on the x axis.  What am I doing wrong?

Note ...

```
str(ec)
```

Results in ...

```
 Time-Series [1:12, 1:2] from 1 to 1.92: 16.3 16.8 15.5 18.2 15.2 17.5 19.8 19 17.5 16 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Mwh" "temp"
```

Comment: You do not need `ggfortify`. The `forecast` package will handle the plot using its own `autoplot.ts` function.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently that's how `autoplot` deals with months in `ts` objects. Using `zoo` and adding some formatting does the job:

```
autoplot(as.zoo(ec), facet = TRUE) + scale_x_date(date_labels = '%b')
```

[image]